# Reading a .sql file from local Resources when Running my job on Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, compile-time

Using the following command in spark/scala to read a long SQL query that I have put in the resources table.

```
  val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("wbs_element.sql")
  val query = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines.mkString
```

I expected it to work fine as the resources files must be read on compile-time when I run .assembly. However, it works fine only when I compile/run the program locally.

On a cluster, it gives the following error:

```
User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/wbs_element.sql (No such file or directory)
```

I'm guessing the program is still not reading the .sql in compile time and it is looking for that file on the cluster, in runtime. Could you please tell me what command I should use to be able to read the file locally on compile time?

Comment: How do you compile your jar? Are you using `sbt-assembly` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scala issue with reading file from resources directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543460/scala-issue-with-reading-file-from-resources-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple options reading at runtime depending on what environment and how you deploy your application, for example:

- In case you want to have this file configurable in `cluster` deploy mode you should pass it as part of the spark-submit command with the `--files` option to upload to the driver (and other nodes)
- In case you want to use `client` mode in spark-submit, you can access it as a local file(your driver will run on the machine where you submit your application)

However, if you really want to read the file at compile time and compile the SQL string into your source, I would rather look into the direction of scala metaprogramming/macros.  [What is a simple way to define a string constant to be the contents of a file at compile-time (in Scala)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785495/what-is-a-simple-way-to-define-a-string-constant-to-be-the-contents-of-a-file-at)